# Property Specification Language (PSL) in VHDL-2008

Tags: vhdl, fpga, verification, register-transfer-level, psl

In my recent project I want use assertion verification. VHDL-2008 have integrated support PSL. But I can't find "starter guide" or something for get started with it. I only find one book "A Practical Introduction to PSL" and I can't buy it at my location.

Do anyone have links on tutorials or some books on PSL?
Maybe another suggestions of how introduce in PSL technology?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/psl/) can help? Books: [A Practical Introduction to PSL](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0387353135/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0387353135&linkCode=as2&tag=electsystelev-20), [Using PSL/Sugar with Verilog and VHDL](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0970539444/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0970539444&linkCode=as2&tag=electsystelev-20).